# Creating HTML elements with jQuery: what’s the correct approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Recently I did a [Backbone tutorial over on Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbonejs-part-1--net-24277) and I saw a really weird way of creating a HTML element with jQuery, the author was saying to create it like this:

```
var select = $('</select>', {
    html: '<option value="all">All</option>'
});
```

But I thought that it was definitely incorrect so I just changed the `select` element to have no forward slashes:

```
var select = $('<select>', {
    html: '<option value="all">All</option>'
});
```

So after I finished the tutorial, I took a look at the comments and one commenter said the it should be written like this:

```
var select = $('<select/>', {
    html: '<option value="all">All</option>'
});
```

This worked fine too but I’m confused: what is the difference between the three? I’m sure the first one (`</select>`) doesn’t work but what is the advantage of using `<select/>` over `<select>`? Does it even make a difference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one on your list won't work, the other two both work the same.

Personally, I prefer to use `<select>` because to me that's the most readable. If you prefer to put the slash in, go for it - it will work just fine, it's just a matter of readability.

You can also use `$("<select></select>")` if you like, although to me that's messier again.

Also, for adding options, it's better to add them like you are doing the select, rather than coding the raw html as a string, eg:

```
var options = [];

for (var i = Options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    options.push($("<option>", {
       html: Options[i].Title,
       value: Options[i].Value
    }));
}

var select = $("<select>", {
    html: options,
    id: "OptionSelector"
});
```

As pointed out by David below, `$("<select>")` is the correct way according to the documentation, so it probably is better to do it that way, despite the behaviour of the other ways working in my (limited) tests.

Comment: I wouldn't use `<select/>`. That syntax doesn't appear to be allowed by the documentation for jquery, except in the case of tags like `<img/>` which don't have content. You never know what quirks might be in the user's browser, and it's generally safer to do whatever the documentation says, just in case.

Comment: You are correct, it is always better to follow the documentation. I'll amend my answer slightly.

Comment: Rather than invoke jQuery for option-creation, why not use the DOM: `options.push(new Option(Options[i].title, Options[i].value));` (though I'd suggest the variable names are almost certainly going to lead to unexpected errors: `Options`/`options`), (*minimal*) ref: [Option()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option).

Comment: You could also do that, but it's not as flexible and also, IMO, not as nice to read :). The variable names are not what I would suggest people use, they were just the first thing that popped into my head - it's an example after all.

Comment: On top of all that, you just shouldn't be using a "self-closing" tag in html anyway.  Its a leftover from XMLdays.  And this: http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/

Comment: Your responses have made everything alot clearer and thanks for trying to make the code itself even better :D

Comment: More than happy to help :)!